# Unable to fetch all the li items under ul tag through selenium

Tags: selenium, scroll

I tried to fetch all the `li` tags which is under `ul` tag. The `ul` node have 31 `li` child nodes, but using the below snippet it gets 26 only as the count.

```
WebElement ul_stops = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='lstOnwardStopInitial']"));
List<WebElement> links = ul_stops.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

[image: Also refer to screen shot which shows the HTML snippet]

As there are different scroll bar attached to this HTML element, to avoid element visibility issue, the below code is for page scroll down although 'e-vhandlespace' class is of customized scrollbar

```
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",driver.findElement(By.className("e-vhandlespace")));
```

The below code is not helping in scrolling down also:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='lstOnwardStopInitial_container']//*[@class='e-vhandlespace']/div[1]")));
actions.click().perform();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).perform();
```

Comment: did you tried with li tag class name or with any other attributes related to li tag

Comment: @Anjana Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Yes i tried locating li tag with  xpath and css locator, able to locate it but it returns only 26 list items not 31

Comment: @DebanjanB, thanks i understood, sure will take care of them i future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the scroll bar issue by pressing Keys.DOWN every time i traverse the li items. One time action of key down wasn't working. It was neither scrolling down nor fetching the li items info & not allowing to interact with any li child nodes.

```
WebElement ul_stops = driver.findElement(By.xpath(lst_StopIntial));
List<WebElement> links = ul_stops.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement e  : links)
    {
        actions.moveToElement(e);
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).perform();
        System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```

Above thing worked
Thanks
Anjana

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at the numeration of the li-items. there is a gap between 12 and 17 so you are getting all items.

Comment: oh yeah, but they are also of li tag elements right

Comment: got it due to numeration issue just the count is the problem..but i am getting all the items.. now only issue is operating on that is possible only if that particular data set is visible. To make it visible i need to scroll down that particular scrollbar..but this doesn't have iframes, just div class is different..But still scroll down doesn't happen